# How can I send a confirmation mail to an email ID from local host without a domain name?

Tags: php, mysql

Once my code is run in PHP, it says that the confirmation mail has been sent successfully, but the mail has not been received at the target mail ID. I have used the `mail()` function in PHP to send the confirmation mail and I have also installed Postfix on my Ubuntu. What is the problem here?

```
<?php
     include('config.php');
     $tb_name = temp_members_db; 
     $confirm_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];
     $country = $_POST['country'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO  $tb_name(confirm_code,name,email,password,country) VALUES ('$confirm_code','$name','$email','$pass','$country')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

     if($result) {
          $to = $email;
          $sub = "Your Confirmation Code";
          $message = "Your confirmation code is" . $confirm_code;
          $send = mail($to,$sub,$message);
          var_export($send);
    } else {
          echo "Havent found email ID in our database";
    }

   if($send) {
         echo "Sent the confirmation link to your email ID";
   } else {
         echo "Sending failed";
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Please, provide more details: show the code that you've tried.

Comment: Yes can you check it now please :)

Comment: Can you send email from the command line?

Comment: Are you using a WAMP server? If yes, you can't send mails using it. Instead use the phpmailer class and your gmail account

Comment: I am not able to send emails through command line either

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched on the SMTP function on the localhost server?

If not enabled the SMTP and mail functions

Answer (score 0):

Use PHPMailer class. Very easy to install and use. The PHP `mail()` function usually sends via a local mail server, typically fronted by a `sendmail` binary on Linux, BSD and OS X platforms, however, Windows usually doesn't include a local mail server; PHPMailer's integrated SMTP implementation allows email sending on Windows platforms without a local mail server.

Just download the class files from here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Example:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
```

Set SMTP and if you want to use secure encryption (ssl,tls and ports)

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // If you want to use encryption, `ssl` also accepted

$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to(or port 25,465 etc)
```

Set fields like from, to, bcc, subject, email body etc.

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
                                                      // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```